# <terminated> xyz debug [c/c application] in opencv eclipse

Tags: c, opencv, eclipse-cdt

i am using eclipse with opencv 2.1 and MinGW in windows 7. i am trying to display an image, i build the code succefully but when i try to run the xyz.exe it is showing  xyz debug[c/c++ application]. i posted my code  below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>



int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
 IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("Koala.jpg");
 if (!img)
     printf("Image can NOT Load!!!\n");
 cvNamedWindow("Example",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
 cvShowImage("Example", img);
 cvWaitKey(0);
 cvReleaseImage(&img);
 cvDestroyWindow("Example");


return 0;

}
```

when i run the xyz.exe it is not showing the image, not even a blank window.  image is valid and it is in same folder.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. I'm using MS Visual Studio 2005. I suggest the obvious debugging steps: strip out all the image loading and just try to display a window, check all return values, etc. Good luck.

Comment: @will Nelson i am using eclipse helios with mingw.is there any problem with eclipse?